# Convert react page to pdf with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I want to create a pdf file in javascript. It should be based on a html page.
For that I built following simple react component:

```
import { FC, LegacyRef, forwardRef } from 'react';

export interface MyComponentProps {
    ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>;
}

export const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = forwardRef(
    (props, ref: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        return (
            <>
                <style>
                    {`
            * {
                color: black;
            }
            `}
                </style>
                <div
                    ref={ref}
                    style={{
                        width: '21cm',
                        height: '29.7cm',
                        margin: '30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm',
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        padding: '1cm 1cm',
                    }}
                >
                    <img
                        style={{
                            float: 'right',
                            width: '5cm',
                            color: 'black',

                            filter: 'grayscale(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(0)',
                        }}
                        src="/ember_logo_beta.svg"
                        alt=""
                    />
                    My Test Text
                </div>
            </>
        );
    },
);
```

If I show this component on a page I see a A4 scaled component.
Now I want to use this component to create a pdf with jsPdf.
For that I'm using following code:

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import { FC, LegacyRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from '...';


const Preview: FC = props => {
    const pdfRef: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null);

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                onClick={() => {
                    const content = pdfRef.current;
                    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
                    doc.html(content, {
                        callback: function (doc) {
                            doc.save('sample.pdf');
                        },
                    });
                }}
            >
                Download
            </Button>
            <div>
                <MyComponent ref={pdfRef} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default Preview;
```

The problem is the resulting pdf contains the page, but it don't fit.  It produces a pdf file with 5 empty pages. Only page 1 contains a very small part of the component. But its not in focus.

Can somebody help?

T